# Validator.isStrongPassword always returning false

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

So, I am using validatorjs on my NodeJS project. I sucessfully managed to use validator.isLength on my username, however, when I use isStrongPassword method to validate my password with the following options, it does not work. It always returns me 'false'. Even if I change the options to: 'minNumbers: 1' only it doesn't work properly.

```
try {
const createUser = async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
const { username, password } = req.body;
const existingUser = await prisma.users.findFirst({
where: {
username: username,
},
});


const isUsernameValid = validator.isLength(username, { min: 3 });
const isPasswordValid = validator.isStrongPassword(password, {
         minLength: 8,
         minUppercase: 1,
         minNumbers: 1,
      });
    
    
      console.log(isUsernameValid, "passwordvalid"); //RETURNS ME TRUE
    
    
      console.log(isPasswordValid, "passwordvalid"); // RETURNS ME FALSE
      ...

}
```

What I am doing wrong?

This is my request password:

```
"password": "1234AaBbCcDd"
```

I tried setting my the validation options to 1 number only, but it doesn't return me 'true'

Comment: Where is `isPasswordValid` coming from? I don't see it on this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs

Comment: isPasswordValid is the variable I created to check the result of the validation.

Oh. I tought it was the same package, but this is the package I am using:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've shared what lib you're using, we can answer your question. If you check the docs you'll notice the default options includes `minSymbols: 1`.

[image]

Simply change that to 0 and you're golden.

```
import validator from "validator";


console.log(validator.isStrongPassword("1234AaBbCcDd", {
  minLength: 8,
  minUppercase: 1,
  minNumbers: 1,
  minSymbols: 0,
}))  // true

console.log(validator.isStrongPassword("1234AaBbCcDd@", {  // <-- with a symbol
  minLength: 8,
  minUppercase: 1,
  minNumbers: 1,
}))  // true
```